# Using ELK to get Jenkins build data from logs

Tags: jenkins, elastic-stack

I currently am using filebeat to ship my Jenkins build log from /var/log/jenkins.
I grok the build logs with Logstash so I can display the success/fail etc in Kibana and make some dashboard --> this is working well.
One thing I cannot seem to get is the total build times for the job as a whole.
I am using pipeline and multi pipeline build job types. 
I can see the build stage time totals in the console logs but no matter the logging level I set globally for Jenkins, these do not display in the logs.
Has anyone managed to get this right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have been using this Jenkins logstash-plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logstash+Plugin
successfully to stash the data from Jenkins jobs to elasticsearch.

Supported indexers by this plugins are available in this link
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logstash+Plugin#LogstashPlugin-IndexersCurrentlySupported

We are using the elasticsearch indexer which stashes the data directly to elasticsearch but if you want your data to go via logstash you can use Logstash indexer.

The payload format for the data is as below
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logstash+Plugin#LogstashPlugin-JSONPayloadFormat

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this plugin in the past. 
We use pipelines and this seems to have a limitation.
It only outputs the build result when it has failed as this result is caught in the pipeline --> Whereas if the build succeeds, it only creates this at the end of the pipeline, therefore logStashSend does not get the result. Hence why I am outputting the logs folder of Jenkins.
Are you using freestyle jobs, or pipelines?